# I want to display a number that will change after given time interval...?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display a number that will change after given time in wordpress by any plugin or with custom code.

if there is no plugin available then i will use custom php, please tell me about any plugin.

please answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code to your `functions.php` in root of your theme:

```
function my_number()
{
    // if today is a later date than specified 
    if (wp_date('Y-m-d') > '2023-01-23') {
        return 2;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Then to show your number use the shortcode, that you have created, just add it to your page content:
`[my_number]`